# Jquery image animation without horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've already managed to succeed in doing the same task with the horizontal scrollbar visible when resizing the window (as you can see at [click here #1](http://jsfiddle.net/XnPjL/2/)) but now I want to avoid this undesidered behaviour. I thought to replace the "left" property with "background-position:" in the css and in the js file, but the animation doesn't work at all.... has anyone a clue? 
Here is my last version: [click here #2](http://jsfiddle.net/linuxatico/XnPjL/3)

Comment: your bounding box is 800px wide, each image is 400px wide, those are set values. Not sure what you mean with 'avoid horizontal scrollbar', if the container was flexible and you wanted to hide the overflow of images, you just set the parent container to overflow:hidden

Comment: stile.css: http://pastebin.com/yyWF3KS1

custom.js: http://pastebin.com/NusiP3q9

index.html: http://pastebin.com/S6dC64ne

And you also need a img folder in the same path of these files with inside 3 image files: righe_3.png, righe_2.png, righe_1.png

I want that when I horizontally resize the browser window, the horizontal scrollbar does not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the animating elements inside a div container that has the CSS property `overflow:hidden`

Comment: It's not enough for my code, please see my other comment for deeper explanation

Comment: what is the exact final outcome that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that all the images float over and over and that I won't see again any horizontal scroll bar when resizing the window

Comment: I was mistaken, I set the overflow:hidden property to the images themselves and not to the container of the images. It works, thanks a lot